# laravel routes not working(with rewrite mod enabled)

Tags: php, laravel

laravel routes are not working without /index.php/ even after enabling `a2enmod rewrite`

This is my vhost (is in etc/apache2/sites-enabled)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost/DnD
    ServerAdmin benno@bennonijholt
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/DnD/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory "/var/www/html/DnD/public">
        Allowoverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

This is my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /home/folder/public_folder

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


    ErrorDocument 404 /404-uh-oh.html

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

i have another laravel installation on another machine (also ubuntu 16.04) just like this which is working perfectly fine.

Comment: I don't think anyone can really help you given what we see here. This is some sort of environmental issue. You should be looking at the server and rewrite logs if they are accessible to you.

Comment: `DnD/public/index.php/hello` is working, but not without `index.php/`. are you sure its the environment?

Comment: Given that this specific detail _wasn't in the question_ who knows? [edit] the question and put _everything_ in there that might be relevant, like observed issues and what research you have done. Please read [ask] to see the best way of getting good quality answers to your question.

Comment: Did rewriting work when you were using plain Laravel, without a modified `.htaccess`?

Comment: @jdv i will read that, this is one of my first questions on stackoverflow.